# Disable Windows 7 for hidden files and folder search

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I want to hide all my important folders. Fortunately I did that, but the biggest loophole here is anyone can find my files using their names in search. So if my folder is not visible, anyone can simply type its name in Windows 7 search and he will get it.

So what is the use of hiding it?

Is there any way through which I can disable Windows 7 searching for hidden files and folders?

Answer (score 1):

If you've already set the 'Don't show hidden files' setting in Explorer then hidden files should not be shown in the index, if they are then you might need to re-build your index.

I should say that marking a file as hidden is really only meant to stop accidental modification not as a way to secure sensitive files. For that you need use the file/folders ACL (ie security settings) to restrict access to specified users.

Answer (score 0):

Step-by-step instructions can be found in *[How To Hide Hidden Files and Folders in Windows 7](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/hide-hidden-files-windows-7.htm)* .

Answer (score 0):

If you use different users and those you don't wan't to see your folders don't have admin rights then do as snowdude suggests, make sure only you have the rights to view the given files/folders. Open command prompt and type:

```
cacls "C:\Path\To\Folder" /G YourUserName:F
```

You can also make two simple batch scripts to hide and unhide your folders from search

```
Hide.bat
cacls "C:\Path\To\Folder" /G SYSTEM:F

Unhide.bat
cacls "C:\Path\To\Folder" /G YourUserName:F
```

You need to run the unhide before you can access the folder yourself.

Edit: cacls is actually deprecated in favor of icacls, but cacls removes all access rights but the one you assign, so no need to remove other users' rights.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use [Secret Disk](http://privacyroot.com/software/www/en/sede.php). It can create additional disk(s) on your PC, which can be invisible and locked with a password. You can make your files and folders invisible and protected. Secret Disk does not encrypt any files. Secret Disk only limits access to your files.

It is available in both Free & Pro versions.

Answer (score 0):

You should hide all of your files, not just the folder containing the files.

Put all the files you want to hide into a folder and then hide this folder and hide the *files* in the folder.

After that the search will not find the hidden files.